# Something like ViewBag in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asp.net-mvc-3, viewbag

First of all I want to pardon all true rails developers, for asking is there original like copy. 
My question is: Is there something like ViewBag in Rails, where I can put simple string?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> My question is: Is there something like ViewBag in Rails, where I can put simple string?

No, thanks God, no. Rails didn't do the same mistake as Microsoft by allowing crap like `ViewBag`. You should use a view model if you want to pass data to a view. And by the way, you should use view models to pass data to view in ASP.NET MVC as well :-)

No, I am kidding, you could do this in Rails:

```
def foo
    @name = "foo bar"
end
```

and in the view:

```
<%= @name %>
```

But please, don't use `ViewBag` in ASP.NET MVC. Use view models :-) This sentence makes me laugh. I am repeating it like a gazzilion times a day and I still see dudes using ViewBag. That's incredible.

Comment: Ok :). Can you please provide me with some explanation, because I have noticed that everybody started using it just after it came out (I thing with ASP.NET MVC 3). Thanks a lot.

Comment: Everybody started using what? Are you talking about the forbidden word? I don't wanna talk about this crap. Even mentioning it makes me vomit. Makes me nauseated.